# Allure отчет не формируется если запускать тесты через Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, test-automation

Когда я запускаю тесты локально через Idea и в плагинах нажимаю allure:serve отчет есть.

Но когда я запускаю тесты с Git hub через Jenkins отчетов нету.

Может ли это быть из-за того что в моем репозиторие нету папки **target/allure-results.**?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да. Может быть.

Comment: Получилось решить проблему ?

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк Да там в Path стоит точка, её нужно было убрать :)